# Is there any point working with the new ASP.NET beta versions?

Tags: asp.net

I'm currently getting to grips with ASP.NET, and I'm learning.

At work I can't get the package above beta5 installed (UAC lockdown and won't be approved), it seems like no matter what I do, my apps end up being built on beta 5, even if I do dnvm upgrade etc, and it ends up crossing versions and everything breaks.

Is it worth learning at home and work on beta5 and just use it as my "stable" version?

when will the full version be released?

Comment: You'd better wait till RC2 or simply RTM. http://docs.asp.net is being updated so later there will be enough things to get you started. Don't stick to beta 5 as it is rather old.

Comment: Is RTM ASP.NET 4? What version should I be installing?

Comment: 4 and 5 will be separate releases. ASP.NET 4.6 is an upgrade for 4.5, while 5 is almost a different thing. You can find both downloads from https://get.asp.net

Answer (score 0):

As of today ASP.NET 5 is in its Release candidate 1.
You can see the anouncment [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/11/18/announcing-asp-net-5-release-candidate-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working with ASP.NET 5 RC1 Update 1 and I have to say that it's pretty stable. We're not running it on a production environment, but for development use it's pretty good. It should be production ready as of release RC1, but I haven't tested it.

Anyhoo, if you want to learn the new ASP.NET workflow I can definitely recommend you try the newest version which can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/vnext/).

For your question regarding the use of beta5, no don't use that version. A lot of things have changed since, so if you try to adapt your current applications to beta5, you can start all over again if you install the newest version of ASP.NET 5. The RC1 version is feature complete, so I guess there won't be breaking changes in future releases.

Comment: The dotnet command for RC2 will be a huge change, while there are still bugs for Linux/OS X stacks. I rather say RC 1 is API complete and we can test API compatibility but about stability and performance I am more conservative.

Comment: Kestrell is going to change a lot, but according to the community standups I guess it's quite feature complete. But I have to say, that the community standups aren't that accurate, since they also promised us a stable Kestrell env with RC1, which is not the case :p